# How to access another view's $scope in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, youtube

I use AngularJS to build a web application. Now I make use of the embed plugin of AngularJS YouTube. To be precise: https://github.com/brandly/angular-youtube-embed.

Now I pause my video by the following event listener: `player.pauseVideo();`. I have added this one to a button.

The YouTube embed is on the same page as the above function is called.
The markup of that object is:

```
<youtube-video video-id="video" id="youtube-video" player="player" style="height:450px; width: 100%"></youtube-video>
```

The player attribute on the object is the one you should use to get the link to between the object and the function call.

But now I also want to get access to the player object on another separate view html document. The function on that page doesn't pause the video on the view.html.

Does anyone know how to get also access to the object on another page by using the similar call like `player.pauseVideo();`.

Comment: You say _"another HTML document"_ and then _"another page"_? Do you mean separate web pages or separate views within the Angular application?

Comment: Yes, exactly. @sdgluck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming by the "player object" you are refering to the scope variable `$scope.player` and by "another page" you mean another view, with a different scope, *rendered into the same html document* where the view with the player resides.
If i am right about these assumptions, then you basically have two options, which are both valid w.r.t. the "angular way".

## Using a global controller

You could introduce a page-wide controller (lets call it MasterController) in the html document and define `$scope.player` there. You can then access `$scope.player` in every controller nested into the MasterController. Note that you **must not** assign a value to `$scope.player` on the nested controllers, as this would block the prototypical inheritance mechanism.

## Using events

Every scope in angular is a child to the `$rootScope`. By using `$rootScope.$broadcast` in the controller where you need to trigger a function from the player and `$scope.$listen` in the controller where the player is attached to, you can control your player from every possible place in your app.

---

For deciding which of those ways is better for your use-case, consider the following properties:

1. Events are 'one-way roads', if you need to retrieve any value from the player (say, it's current play position) from outside of the players scope, you would need to implement the same mechanism the other way around, whereas using a global controller is as easy as writing `$scope.player`
2. Events support the development of uncoupled, reuseable components. If you were to implement a video hub which in addition to youtube also supports vimeo and other platforms you could abstract away the control of all those different plugins by using events and just drop-in new video platforms without the need to modify your other views controllers.

I recommend the book "[Learning JavaScript Design Patterns](http://www.addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/)" by Addy Osmani and the angular guide on [scopes](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#!)